# Can i fetch a rest token while in MessageComposeCommandSurface in outlook javascript?

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

When my extension opens from a `MessageReadCommandSurface` ExtensionPoint i can get a token and request the users contacts but if my ExtensionPoint is changed to `MessageComposeCommandSurface` my call to getCallbackTokenAsync fails with the following.

```
{
  "name": "CanOnlyGetTokenForSavedItem",
  "message": "The token can't be retrieved until the item is saved.",
  "code": 9029
}
```

My code running is rather simple.

```
Office.initialize = 
    () => Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, 
    res => console.log(res));
```

Is it possible to query the user's contacts from my add-in on a message compose pane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests you can [save the item](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook) and after saving the item get the token.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(
  function callback(result) {
    // Process the result
  });
```

Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync() is expected to return a  token scoped to the item.(except add-ins with ReadWriteMailbox permission), so it is expecting the item to be saved.

Comment: This answer makes sense, if your add-in does not have ReadWriteMailbox permission. Otherwise this has to be a bug in Outlook.

Comment: Thanks, @SureshGowthamS. This fixed my problem as well however I do have ReadWriteMailbox permission and it was still causing this error. Should I submit this as a bug to the OfficeJS team as you suggested that it would be one in this context?

Comment: @JefCurtis Please go ahead, ideally the API should work even without saving the item for an add-in with ReadWriteMailbox permission.